# datos repetidos select - php

Tags: php

buen dia, tengo dos selects dinamicos, el primer select muestra la información desde la base de datos y el segundo muestra la información dependiendo que selecciono en el primer select hasta ahí todo funciona bien pero necesito que en el primer select no cargue datos repetidos y para eso intento agregar "distinct" en la consulta select del primer select pero al agregar dicha consulta el segundo select no me carga.

index.php

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
 // $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'demo', 'root', 'Base_datos');
  $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','hostcrea_pruebas2','Kenryug=00','hostcrea_pruebas2');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Llenar select a partir de otro con php y mysql</title>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    
  
    
    
    <h2>Llenar un select a partir de otro select con jquery y php</h2>

            <label>SELECT 1 (Tallas)</label>
            
        <select  id="lista1" name="lista1>
        <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
        <?php
     //  funciona y el segundo select carga los datos sin problemas pero aparece
 los datos repetidos en el primer select         //$query = $conexion -> query ("SELECT * FROM dtl_product WHERE idPro_dtl = 95");
     
     //no funciona - auqnue ya no me muestra datos repetidos en el primer select el segundo select no carga
        $query = $conexion -> query ("SELECT distinct talla_dtl FROM dtl_product WHERE idPro_dtl = 95");
        
          while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$valores[idPro_dtl].'">'.$valores[talla_dtl].'</option>';
          }
        ?>
      </select>
      
      
            <br>
            <div id="select2lista"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#lista1').val(0);
        recargarLista();

        $('#lista1').change(function(){
            recargarLista();
        });
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function recargarLista(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"datos.php",
            data:"continente=" + $('#lista1').val(),
            success:function(r){
                $('#select2lista').html(r);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

datos.php

```js
<?php 
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','hostcrea_pruebas2','Kenryug=00','hostcrea_pruebas2');
$continente=$_POST['continente'];

    $sql="SELECT id_dtlPro,
             idPro_dtl,
             color_dtl 
        from dtl_product 
        where idPro_dtl='$continente'";

    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    $cadena="<label>SELECT 2 (color)</label> 
            <select id='lista2' name='lista2'>";

    while ($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $cadena=$cadena.'<option value='.$ver[0].'>'.utf8_encode($ver[2]).'</option>';
    }

    echo  $cadena."</select>";
    

?>
```

Comment: Errores? Ya depuraste el resultado del primer query para ver si trae los datos usados en la segunda query??

Comment: Las dos consultas deberían ser la misma, una con distinct y la otra no?, por que son diferentes y puedes traer otros datos que no especificas en el segundo select.